# Strange error in pandas indexing with range when length >= 1,000,000

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Pandas raises a ValueError when assigning multiple values to a Series (or DataFrame) using range(x) where x > 1. This error is raised **only when its length is one million or larger**.

```py
import pandas as pd

for x in [5, 999999, 1000000]:
    s = pd.Series(index=range(x))
    print('series length =', len(s))
    # assigning value with range(1), always works
    s.loc[range(1)] = 42 
    # reading values with range(x>1), always works
    _ = s.loc[range(2)] 
    # assigning values with range(x>1), fails only len >= 1 million
    s.loc[range(2)] = 42
```

Output:

```py
series length = 5
series length = 999999
series length = 1000000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 9, in <module>
  File "/home/nekobon/.env_exp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 114, in __setitem__
    indexer = self._get_setitem_indexer(key)
  File "/home/nekobon/.env_exp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 109, in _get_setitem_indexer
    return self._convert_to_indexer(key, is_setter=True)
  File "/home/nekobon/.env_exp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1042, in _convert_to_indexer
    return labels.get_loc(obj)
  File "/home/nekobon/.env_exp/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pandas/core/index.py", line 1692, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(_values_from_object(key))
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 137, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3979)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 145, in pandas.index.IndexEngine.get_loc (pandas/index.c:3680)
  File "pandas/index.pyx", line 464, in pandas.index._bin_search (pandas/index.c:9124)
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

I use python 3.4 and pandas 0.17.0. This behavior doesn't seem to be reported yet. Does pandas do anything special on Series with length >= 1,000,000?

Comment: works fine with `s.loc[np.arange(2)] = 42 ` and `s.loc[[0,1]] = 42` unclear why `range(2)` causes it to bork

Comment: Yeah, this is a bug; you should open a ticket on github.  1M is the monotonic index size cutoff for hash tables, and the logic beyond that is borked.

Comment: Thank you. I opened a ticket and it seems like a fix is already submitted [#11652](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/11652). I'm still  curious about this 1M. @DSM, do you know where this 1M threshold is set at?

Comment: It's in [index.pyx](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/index.pyx#L70).

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it. Thanks!